# Function call removed in wordpress

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, function

In wordpress I have written a function call oninput="functionName()"
in  tag and called it. On updating  the page the function gets removed from the page. Can anyone suggest a solution??
Snnippet:
<input id="invest_return_sip" value="10" class="form form-body form-control" name="invest_return_sip" **oninput="calculateSIP()"** type="number" />

Comment: Can you please post some code?

Comment: WordPress sanitizes HTML to prevent [XSS attacks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Cross-site_scripting). If you need to listen to an event I'd suggest using [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) in JS.

Comment: Snnippet:
<input id="invest_return_sip" value="10" class="form form-body form-control" name="invest_return_sip" oninput="calculateSIP()" type="number" />
@grisuu

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.